# Taking limits in a variational PDE with respect to a parameter

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth bounded domain and $B \subset \Omega$ be an open ball, for a given $\epsilon>0$ consider

$$a_\epsilon(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, \qquad x \in \Omega \backslash B \\
\epsilon, \qquad x \in B
\end{cases}$$

Let $f \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$, i.e. $f$ is boundary data of some $H^1(\Omega)$ function, in the sense of traces, and let $u_\epsilon \in H^1(\Omega)$ be the unique weak solution of the problem

$$\begin{cases}
div(a_\epsilon \nabla u_\epsilon) = 0, \qquad &\text{in} \ \Omega \\
u_\epsilon=f, \qquad &\text{on} \ \partial \Omega
\end{cases}$$

Let also $u_0 \in H^1(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})$ be the unique weak solution of

$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u_0 = 0, \qquad &\text{in} \ \Omega \backslash \overline{B} \\
\frac{\partial u_0}{\partial n} = 0 \qquad &\text{on} \ \partial B  \\
u_0=f, \qquad &\text{on} \ \partial \Omega
\end{cases}$$

How can we show that $u_\epsilon \to u_0$ in $H^1(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?

There are the associated Dirichlet energies:

$$E_\epsilon(u_\epsilon) := \int_\Omega a_\epsilon |\nabla u_\epsilon|^2 dx,
\qquad E_0(u_0) = \int_{\Omega \backslash \overline{B}} |\nabla u_0|^2 dx$$

We then have,

$$E_\epsilon(u_\epsilon) = \int_{\Omega \backslash \overline{B}} |\nabla u_\epsilon|^2 dx + \int_B \epsilon |\nabla u_\epsilon|^2 dx $$

The idea should be to prove that $\|u_\epsilon\|_{H^1(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})}$ is bounded uniformly in $\epsilon$, so that we can extract weakly convergent subsequence with a limit $u_0 \in H^1(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})$. This limit clearly satisfies $\Delta u_0 = 0$ in $\Omega \backslash \overline{B}$, by just using the weak convergence and the weak formulations of PDEs. I don't know how to obtain the Neumann boundary condition for $u_0$ on $\partial B$. Then if we show the convergence of energies $E_\epsilon(u_\epsilon) \to E_0(u_0)$ we can conclude that $u_\epsilon \to u_0$ strongly in $H^1(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})$.

We clearly have that $\|\nabla u_\epsilon\|_{L^2(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})}$ is bounded uniformly in $\epsilon$, for $\epsilon \leq 1$, using that the energy $E_\epsilon(v)$ is minimized for $v=u_\epsilon$. But I don't know how to conclude the boundedness of $\|u_\epsilon\|_{L^2(\Omega \backslash \overline{B})}$.

Can one also consider a limit $\epsilon \to \infty$? If so what would be the limiting problem?  Thank you.